# How can I check to see if an http request has no query strings in ASP.Net Core web API

Tags: httprequest, query-string, asp.net-core-webapi, request.querystring, querystringparameter

I am working on an ASP.Net Core web API using REST verbs with optional query string parameters.

For example, the API call looks like this;

```
http://localhost:5010/servicetypecode?stc=123
```

or 
    http://localhost:5010/servicetypecode?mailclasscode=fc

I am using code like this to set up the query strings

```
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] string mailclasscode, [FromQuery] string stc) { ... }
```

So, in my method body, I am evaluating each string individually like this...

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailclasscode)) { ... }


    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stc)) { ... }
```

However, I would like to allow my users to just make a straight up GET to the API with no query string parameters provided and return a list of all records, unfiltered.

So a call like this;

```
http://localhost:5010/servicetypecode
```

But I would prefer not to have to do this in my method body, especially if I were to have a lot of query string parameters;

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailclasscode) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(stc)) { ... }
```

Is there a way to simply determine if no query string parameters were provided without evaluating every possible query string parameter?

Also, is there a better way to evaluate query string parameters than testing every possible parameter, in the case where I were to pass a lot of different query string parameters?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the incoming request.

```
if (this.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.HasValue)
```

Also as a note, if you have a lot of query string parameters, you can use a single class instead of multiple parameters in the method signature.

Comment: ATerry, thanks. This worked perfectly. The other part of the question I was asking was more about a better way of processing multiple query string parameters than just using multiple if statements within the body of the method (whether I am using multiple query strings or a class in the method signature). I am trying to use a single GET method but provide multiple filtering options so, currently, I am testing for each possible query string parameter using multiple if statements. This works but looks a bit cluttered.

Comment: If you looking to do more of a query based api, almost like a data access api, you can make use of IQueryable with a limited or full implementation of OData. Also, you can look at GraphQL. These are both frameworks that will take your returned IQueryable and apply the necessary filters.